# Pagination to display 10 item using php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have more than 100000 data in database,when i try to show all the data in front end it take more than 5mins to loading all the data,so i decide to use pagination.

here i am try displaying the 10 record per page i am showing the first 10 record successfully with pagination looks like this `(? previous123456789...1235012351next ?)` but if i am check the next page or select any page in pagination it refreshing the page it pass the selected page in the url `http://localhost/var/cms/page.php?page=2` and it not displaying the next 10 data it always displays the first 10 data.

below is my code can any one tell me how to show the next 10 data when next page click thanks.

full code:

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '1234fedf';
$dbDatabase = 'cms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");


    $tbl_name="contact";       //your table name
    $adjacents = 3;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    //print $query;
    $queryRes = mysql_query($query);

    if($queryRes === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes))
{
    $total_pages=$rows['num'];
    //print $total_pages;
}




    $targetpage = "page.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;                                //how many items to show per page

        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT contact.`id` , contact.`contactgroup` , contact.`media` ,contact.`media2` , contact.`email1` , contact.`nationality` , contact.`country3` , contact.`twon` , contact.`area` , contact.`gender` , contact.`married` , contact.`children` , contact.`driverslicense` FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
    //print $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    //print $lastpage; 
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">? previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">? previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next ?</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next ?</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";     
    }
?>

    <?php

    echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Contactgroup</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Nationality</th>
<th>Country3</th>
<th>Twon</th>
<th>Area</th>
<thGender</th>
<th>Married</th>
<th>Children</th>
<th>Driverslicense</th>
</tr>";
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

         echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['contactgroup'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['email1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['nationality'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['country3'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['twon'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['area'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['gender'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['married'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['children'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $rows['driverslicense'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";



        }

        echo "</table>";
    ?>

    <?php echo $pagination;?>
```

Comment: http://phpsense.com/2007/php-pagination-script/

Comment: you can check this slides for pagination http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/view?login=Eweaver&preview=no&slideid=1&title=efficient-pagination-using-mysql

Comment: Now might be a good time to change your password.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `$start` variable to `0` when no any page found. If page found then multiply page with limit and Add 1 to get `$start` value like following

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!="")
  $start = ($_GET['page'] * 10) + 1; 
else
  $start = 0;
```

For more detail Check [Here](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html).

Comment: i tried but it showing error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in C:\wamp\www\var\cms\page.php on line 34

Comment: if(isset($_GET['page'] && $_GET['page']!="") in this line

Comment: its works but can you tell me why my pagination look like this ? previous123456789...1235012351next ? also prevoius page is not working and if i click second page then i am not able to click the first page

Comment: You have to use css for display with format and you have to compare with I given link for reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56522/discussion-between-xavi-and-sadikhasan).